# How to import a module from C:\Users\myusername\.qgis2\processing\scripts

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I have a user script which is located in `C:\Users\'myusername'\.qgis2\processing\scripts`. 
[image]

I call script "plotWLayer1" containing the line

```
import funcPlot
```

User script funcPlot is also located in the same path but when I execute the script Qgis logs the following:

```
No module name funcPlot
```

I have tried adding the path using,

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
```

with the same result. 
What am I doing wrong? My intention is to give these scripts to fellow users within my company but if I hard code sys.append() the script would have to modified per user.

**Update 1:**
For the moment I am using the following code under the assumption that only the username for different users in my company would change but any suggestions would still be welcomed.

```
import getpass
username = getpass.getuser()
import sys
exePath='C:\\Users\\'+username+'\.qgis2\\processing\\scripts'
sys.append(exePath)
```

Comment: Have you try to print `os.getcwd()` where it's searching ?

Comment: I did but I am not sure where it is output. I checked the log and I found some execution in C:\OSGeo4wShell\..., without the output of print()

Comment: Update my answer

Answer (score 2):

For import "**funcPlot**" in you "**plotWLayer1**" you can use this script:

```
import imp, os.path
from qgis.core import QgsMessageLog

def import_(filename):
    (path, name) = os.path.split(filename)
    (name, ext) = os.path.splitext(name)
    print name
    print path

    (file, filename, data) = imp.find_module(name, [path])
    return imp.load_module(name, file, filename, data)

funcPlot = import_("C:\Users\'myusername'\.qgis2\processing\scripts\\funcPlot.py")
```

And if funcPlot.py have a function for example `def myFunction()`

Call it using `funcPlot.myFunction()`

**Update:**

Other way is using `exePath=os.path.expanduser('~') +"\\.qgis2\\processing\\scripts"`  because is not necesary that all user have a **C** driver letter

I hope this helps you